PKCS #11 API not accesible in JAVA
I am trying to asccess pkcs#11 in java but i am getting this error, while tryig to use or while importing
Error: The type sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 is not accessible
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
The type sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 is not accessible
This is the code sample
Class<?> sunPKCS11Class = Class.forName("sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11");
        Provider provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11("softhsm.cfg");
        Security.addProvider(provider);
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", provider);


Have you consulted the PKCS#11 Reference Guide for the Java version that you are using? By the way, what Java version are you using?
